# SharePoint form navigating to allitems.aspx after submit form

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I hope you can help me with some basic information, as I am pretty new in the SharePoint world.

I created a list for users to fill out through a form. After submitting the form the users will always be directed to the allitems.aspx site of the list. I want them to navigate after submitting the form to a "Thank You for submitting the form" page.

What I tried in the SharePoint integration properties is to edit the OnSave properties to

*SubmitForm(Form1);Launch("pageURL")*

That created an error saying unexpected signs were used in the form.

Any idea or solutions what I could try?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: What SharePoint version are you using? Are you customizing the list's default forms using SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

When do you see the error, is it right after you type the forum or when you publish the form?

I’ve just tested with the same function with following forum and it seems to be working fine:

```
SubmitForm(SharePointForm1);
Launch("https://www.google.com/")
```

Try writing the `Launch()` function in the next line or switch to another URL and see the result.

--

Besides using the **Launch** function via *SharePointIntegration > OnSave*, here is one more option:

Create a new screen to display the "*Thank You for submitting the form*" message inside PowerApps form, then use **[Navigate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-navigate)** function to redirect to the new screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem was, in Germany we need the double semicolon ";;". Now it works.

Comment: @simon1608 ok, thanks for sharing